# NetLogo programming questions: check agent color/have breeds pass through one another

Tags: netlogo, traffic-simulation

Some basic programming questions in NetLogo:

- 1) In the **`is-agent?` *value*** command. How can I specifically check if the agent with id = 4 is green or not?

  By contrast, `is-agent? green`   would only be true if any of the agents is green.
- 2) I have made two breeds of agents and they stop when they collide with each other. How can I make them pass over each other?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1)To check the color of a turtle/agent you can do:

```
let the-agent ...get the agent some way...
if ( [color] of the-agent = orange) [show "the agent is orange"]
```

2) I'm puzzled. Turtles in netlogo do not collide with each other, by default, they pass over each other. The only thing that can stop a turtle from going "forward" is the end of the grid. You must have written some code that makes them collide.